# Issue with numpy all() and any()

Tags: python, numpy

I like to check if an array contains any negative or zero element.

To do this, I tried using `numpy.any` or `numpy.all`, but when I ran the following code:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,1,-1,-2,3,5])
print(arr)
if np.any(arr) <= 0:
    print('negative or zero element(s) exist')
else:
    print('all positive')
```

it returns `'all positive'`. But the array contains negative and zero elements, so I was not expecting this.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix?

Comment: `np.any(test_array <= 0):`

Comment: Be sure to upvote any answers below that you find useful. Then accept the one that helped the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if np.any(test_array) <= 0:
```

You are currently comparing if the return value of `any()` is less than or equal to zero. Instead, you need to compare with each element of the array:

```
if np.any(test_array <= 0):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use np.all() to get the result:

```
if (a <= 0).all():
    print('negative or zero element(s) exist')
else:
    print('all positive')
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow. You can edit your question at any time to fix typos or otherwise improve it. This is preferrable to posting errata in comments.

Comment: With that said, you solution uses `ndarray.all()`, not `numpy.all()`. I suggest you update your answer to explain the difference.